# Deleting characters from multiple column headings and saving it

Tags: r, excel

I am currently working with what was originally an excel spreadsheet, and I am now working with it in R.

I need to delete the words `"Raw1"` from about 400 hundred column headings.

**I have used this command with some success:**

```
gsub(pattern = "Raw1", replacement = "", x = names(data), fixed = TRUE)
```

However, I now have two problems both revolve around me, basically, not being able to "save" the file like this. I also need to remove "r1" from about 200 hundred others, but when I do, "r1" deletes as expected, but "Raw1" is back again. Also, if I download the data back to excel, the column names appear as they were before gsub.

Can anyone shed any light on how to make it permanent?

Comment: are you not assigning results to a variable !

Answer (score 0):

Shot from the hip, but are you saving the changes? Namely, you need to assign the names back. In code, this would be

```
names(data) <- gsub(pattern = "Raw1", replacement = "", x = names(data), fixed = TRUE)
```

Comment: Wow! Doh...  you're spot on. Thanks!